# Account Merge Request

Tags: support, status-completed, user-accounts

I would like to merge the following two accounts:

https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/411/mike-riverso
https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/4445/mike-riverso

I've tried to change the e-mail addresses so that they're the same, but the system refuses to let me because they're already in use. I'd like to keep the older user (411) of course, so that I can keep all my stats. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

Please use the following tool found under the "contact us" page in the footer:

https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge

This is now the only way to get your accounts merged.

Comment: Ah, looks like that worked. I tried it before but couldn't make it stick. Now it seems to work fine. Thanks. :)